# MLflow UI returns invalid address when trying to run it locally on remote machine

Tags: mlflow

I'm trying to use the MLflow UI on a remote Linux machine and access the browser from my local laptop that I use to access the server. I'm trying to do this by running the command `mlflow ui --host 192.108.1.2 --port 1234`. However, I keep getting the following log message:

```
[2023-04-28 09:33:59 +0900] [31040] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-04-28 09:33:59 +0900] [31040] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('192.168.1.2', 1234)
[2023-04-28 09:33:59 +0900] [31040] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-04-28 09:34:00 +0900] [31040] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('192.168.1.2', 1234)
[2023-04-28 09:34:00 +0900] [31040] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: Port not published on the remote machine :-) ?